# Segmentation fault when attempting enqueue

Tags: c

I have a simple function that should perform enqueuing based on the following algorithm:

```
Algorithm: ENQUEUE (Q, ITEM)
[Q is an array represent queue and ITEM is deleted item]
1. [check overflow]
If Rear = MAX - 1 then
a) Print: Queue is Full
b) Return
2. Set Rear = Rear + 1
3. Q[Rear] = ITEM
4. Return
```

I have attempted two approaches and one provides me with a `segmentation fault` error, and I cannot understand why.

Here is the working implementation:

```
#define MAXSIZE 255
typedef struct Stack {
    int Q[MAXSIZE]; 
    int rear;
} Stack_t;

int enqueue(int item,int(*Q)[item] ){
    int rear;
    if (rear == sizeof(*Q)/sizeof((*Q)[0])-1){
        printf("Queue is Full!");
        return -1;
    }
    rear++;
    (*Q)[rear] = item;
    return rear;
}

int main(void){
    Stack_t s = {.rear = -1};
    int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int item = 2;
    int result;
    result = enqueue(item, &arr);
    printf("\nResult: {%i}", arr[result]);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print out:

```
Queue is Full!
Result: {0}%
```

Whereas, the original implementation I had in mind would not work, it goes likeso:

```
int enqueue(int(*Q)[], int item, int size){
    int rear;
    if (rear == size-1){
        printf("Queue is Full!");
        return -1;
    }
    rear++;
    (*Q)[rear] = item;
    return rear;
}

int main(void){
    Stack_t s = {.rear = -1};
    Stack_t q = {.Q = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int item = 2;
    int result;
    int size = sizeof(q.Q)/sizeof(q.Q[0]);
    result = enqueue(&q.Q, item, size);
    printf("\nResult: {%i}", q.Q[result]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to indexing `structs` and recently learnt them from my latest question (before this one.) So perhaps `q.Q` is not the exact expression, otherwise, the size is not properly captured.

Comment: This sequence of lines in your code:  `int rear;
    if (rear == size-1)`, leaves `rear` uninitialized before using in a comparison statement, causing unpredictable results.  What should `rear` be initialized to?  If the following is used: `int rear = item;` then the output is _"Result: {2}"_

Comment: Also, the _working_ code also has that same variable  uninitialized.  Both instances of these variables should be initialized.  It is only by chance that the _working_ code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array in the struct to store the enqueued integers.
Pass a pointer to the structure to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 255

typedef struct Stack {
    int Q[MAXSIZE];
    int rear;
} Stack_t;

int enqueue ( int item, Stack_t *q){
    int max = ( sizeof q->Q / sizeof q->Q[0]) - 1;
    if ( q->rear == max) {
        printf ( "Queue is Full!\n");
        return q->rear;
    }
    q->rear++;
    q->Q[q->rear] = item;
    return q->rear;
}

int main ( void) {
    Stack_t s = {.rear = -1};
    int item = 2;
    int result;
    result = enqueue ( item, &s);
    printf ( "Result: {%i}\n", s.Q[result]);
    item = 12;
    result = enqueue ( item, &s);
    printf ( "Result: {%i}\n", s.Q[result]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! I was afraid of linked lists but after a few extra tutorials, I can now understand their implementation. Thank you!